# Cache images wp8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have array of `URI`that contains likns to images from internet. I want have access to this ones without always connection to the internet. I see such scenario: in first start of my app i download all images to the appdata folder, and make array of internal `URI`. Than I save this array in localsettings.

But maybe there is way to cache  images with standart librarys of C# and use original array  of `URI` to get access to images from offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good open source library that can help you with that.

[Q42.WinRT](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT)

It has something called ImageExtensions.CacheUri which means that it automatically caches images based on Uri.

```
<Image q42controls:ImageExtensions.CacheUri="uri of your image" />
```

And don't forget the q42controls namespace.

```
xmlns:q42controls="clr-namespace:Q42.WinRT.Controls;assembly=Q42.WinRT.Phone"
```

Comment: I want to do something like that:  I enable data transfer than use such code 'URI imgURI = new URI("http://somesite.com/image1.png");   classThatILookingFor.cache(imgURI)'     Than i switch off data tranfer and use such code:    'imageControlOnMainpage.Source=imageUri;'     Can i do this with Q42.WinRT library?

Comment: @lehkap this automatically caches image the first time it loads it from the Internet. You jhust set the uri through CacheUri property. Check out the library for more details about implementation.